# How to plot a histogram with uniform space between uneven data points?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

So I have an array y that contains powers of 2, like 1, 2, 4, 8, 16,... and I want to put them in a histogram to see how many of each shows up. But when I plot them they turn out like this:[image]

My question is: how do I get them close together, with 1,2,4,8,... all evenly spaced instead of 32 and 64 being way further like this. My sample code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=(2,1,8,1,64,8,2,8,32,0)

plt.hist(y,bins=128)
plt.xlabel('Power of 2')
plt.ylabel('Number of times show up')
plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Comment: What if a number (say 16) does not occur in the list. Do you still want to show it on the axes?

Comment: In that case, no. But if it's possible, please do show me both ways. :D

Comment: Look at `numpy.unique()` with the argument `return_counts`. Then plot those counts as function of the index, (e.g. with a `bar` plot) and label the ticks with the unique numbers.

Comment: So I put in u,indices=np.unique(y,return_counts = True) and plot from u, but the same thing happened. The spacing is still stretched between numbers that are furthuer away from each other. I tried to put a "string" in the array, but then the order of the number is all messed up (64 shows up before 8, etc.) I also tried to change the array into string by putting plt.xticks(y,str(y)) or plt.xticks(u,str(u)), but then the x axis is completely messed up.

Comment: By "plot those counts as function of the index" I meant something like `plt.bar(np.arange(len(u)), counts); plt.xticks(np.arange(len(u)), u)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Show the unique numbers

You may use `numpy.unique` with the argument `return_counts`. Then plot those counts as function of the index, (e.g. with a bar plot) and label the ticks with the unique numbers.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=(2,1,8,1,64,8,2,8,32,0)

u, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)

plt.bar(np.arange(len(u)), counts)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(u)), u)
plt.xlabel('Power of 2')
plt.ylabel('Number of times show up')
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Show all powers of 2

In case you want to show all powers of 2, even those that don't appear in the list of input values, the solution is more tricky. Especially since you have `0` in the list, which is not a power of 2.

One could use a loop here and fill a new array with the values from the counts.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

y=(2,1,8,1,64,8,2,8,32,0)

u, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
lookup = defaultdict(int, zip(u, counts))
maxpow = np.log2(np.max(y))
print maxpow
complete = np.concatenate(([0], 2**np.arange(0,maxpow)))
complete_counts = np.zeros_like(complete)
for i, p in enumerate(complete):
    complete_counts[i] = lookup[p]

plt.bar(np.arange(len(complete)), complete_counts)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(complete)), complete)
plt.xlabel('Power of 2')
plt.ylabel('Number of times show up')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I have one more question if you don't mind: Is there a way for me to change all the zeroes value in the array to display under "Fail" on the plot or as some "string" instead?

Comment: Sure you can set the ticklabels to anything you want via  `plt.xticks`.